# How can I return the primitive data type from polymorphism?

Tags: haskell

Given some custom sum data type,

```
data Type = Thing Char | NotThing Char
```

How can I use `==` to compare between the Char here and some other Char? As below:

```
let f = 'a'
NotThing e == f
>>> True
```

Of course, this code cannot compare between types as NotThing is a separate type to Char.

Comment: The standard `==` function takes arguments of the same type, so you can't do that. You may create a different function that does take `char` and `Type` arguments. It isn't clear what you mean by "return the primitive data type from polymorphism" though. Haskell doesn't really make a meaningful distinction between primitive and non-primitive data types.

Comment: And there's no polymorphism anywhere in your example. (If you were to implement something analogous in an OO language then you might use inheritance-polymorphism, yes – but in Haskell, polymorphism is quite different.) In general, two constructors of a data type will encapsulate completely different fields.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. With that function, how can I compare those characters though? How can I access that Char?

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `compareTypeWithChar :: Type -> Char -> Bool; compareTypeWithChar (NotThing a) b = a == b; compareTypeWithChar _ _ = False;` (or whatever you want to do when your Type contains a Thing).

Answer (score 3):

If `x :: Char` and `y :: Type`, then the following expressions (among others) are well-typed:

```
y == Thing x
y == NotThing x
y `elem` [Thing x, NotThing x]
case y of { Thing x' -> x == x'; NotThing x' -> x == x' }
```

Probably the last one is closest to what you want. I would abstract slightly and write

```
extract :: Type -> Char
extract (Thing x') = x'
extract (NotThing x') = x'
```

because I would expect that to occasionally be useful in other contexts. With that in hand, the following expression is also well-typed:

```
extract y == x
```

Of course, you'll want to pick a better name than `extract`, just like you'll do for `Type`, `Thing`, and `NotThing`.